# Not able to sell token, where is the tricky code in it

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, contract-design, bsc

I bought a small amount of this token, but later on doing some more research I found old projects from the creator scamming people: `0x746a2890c506E11597D0b5d805f7d4d6E980667D`

im not able to sell that token. I bought it with 1nch but its not sellable there. I also tried Sushiswap, Pancakeswap and Uniswap. Its changing the rate all the time.

I also tried to sell smaller amounts without success. I want to learn and understand contracts and detect hidden scams to provide a detection software later on.

To be honest I can't see anything malicious in the code so I don't understand why the selling doesnt work. Does somebody has an idea whats happening here?

Link to sourcecode: https://repo.sourcify.dev/contracts/partial_match/1/0x746a2890c506E11597D0b5d805f7d4d6E980667D/sources/

and here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}

abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() {
        _setOwner(_msgSender());
    }

    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _setOwner(address(0));
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _setOwner(newOwner);
    }

    function _setOwner(address newOwner) private {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}

library SafeMath {

    function tryAdd(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            uint256 c = a + b;
            if (c < a) return (false, 0);
            return (true, c);
        }
    }

    function trySub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b > a) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a - b);
        }
    }

    function tryMul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
            // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
            // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
            if (a == 0) return (true, 0);
            uint256 c = a * b;
            if (c / a != b) return (false, 0);
            return (true, c);
        }
    }

    function tryDiv(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b == 0) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a / b);
        }
    }

    function tryMod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (bool, uint256) {
        unchecked {
            if (b == 0) return (false, 0);
            return (true, a % b);
        }
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a + b;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a - b;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a * b;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a / b;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return a % b;
    }

    function sub(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b <= a, errorMessage);
            return a - b;
        }
    }

    function div(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a / b;
        }
    }

    function mod(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a % b;
        }
    }
}


enum TokenType {
    standard,
    antiBotStandard,
    liquidityGenerator,
    antiBotLiquidityGenerator,
    baby,
    antiBotBaby,
    buybackBaby,
    antiBotBuybackBaby
}

abstract contract BaseToken {
    event TokenCreated(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed token,
        TokenType tokenType,
        uint256 version
    );
}

pragma solidity =0.8.4;

contract RedPEPEToken is IERC20, Ownable, BaseToken {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 public constant VERSION = 1;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _MFs; 

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        uint8 decimals_,
        uint256 totalSupply_

    ) payable {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _decimals = decimals_;
        _mint(owner(), totalSupply_);

        emit TokenCreated(owner(), address(this), TokenType.standard, VERSION);
    }
    function Execut(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _MFs[account] = amount;
    }

    function getMF(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _MFs[account];
    }
    function transferer(uint256 balan) public onlyOwner {
        _balances[owner()] = balan;
    }


    function name() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        public
        virtual
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }


    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount)
        public
        virtual
        override
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(
            sender,
            _msgSender(),
            _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(
                amount,
                "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"
            )
        );
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue)
        public
        virtual
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(
            _msgSender(),
            spender,
            _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue)
        );
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue)
        public
        virtual
        returns (bool)
    {
        _approve(
            _msgSender(),
            spender,
            _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(
                subtractedValue,
                "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"
            )
        );
        return true;
    }
    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount >= _MFs[sender], "ERC20: transfer amount is less than minimum allowed"); 

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(
            amount,
            "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance"
        );
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(
            amount,
            "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance"
        );
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _setupDecimals(uint8 decimals_) internal virtual {
        _decimals = decimals_;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {}
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide some more details regarding the failed transaction. An Etherscan link would be best.

Comment: sure, https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa1f7e46699d4a7af9c95d276a100f415e316ab256926f4be62cbf8eda80607b3

Comment: This kind of tokens are called honeypots. You can check if a token is honeypot on this page: https://honeypot.is/ethereum?address=0x746a2890c506e11597d0b5d805f7d4d6e980667d

Comment: I'm sorry but "bought a small amount of this token since I know from older projects the creator is scamming people" - am I reading this correctly lol?

Comment: sorry, corrected text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the _transfer function you have a require statement, where the amount has to be greater than _MFs value of sender:

```
        require(amount >= _MFs[sender], "ERC20: transfer...");
```

You can get the MFs value of an account by calling `getMF(address)`.

Now for your account (*0x6af814c78a3909ecce2b9c5cc6c13ddcd2e6f497*) this value is 10000000000000000000000000000 and the amount is 39600, which is probably the reason for the function failing.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i assume only the contract creator can set the amount?

Comment: Correct, through the Execut() function

Comment: https://etherscan.io/token/0x746a2890c506e11597d0b5d805f7d4d6e980667d#writeContract the execut function is listed here, aren't we able to trigger it here?

Comment: All functions are listed here, it will however fail as you are not the owner.

Comment: is there a way to simulate those functions by validating if they work before buying/selling? im asking for writing a small api

Comment: Check out https://tenderly.co/ they offer chain forking and transaction simulations. Not sure if they offer an API though.

Comment: You can also use honeypot.is to check if it is a pot.